# List the first words per line from a text file in Python

Tags: python, file, text, line, cpu-word

I need to select the first word on each line and make a list from them from a text file:

[I would copy the text but it's the formatting is quite screwed up. will try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2uLC.png)
All the other text is unnecessary.

I have tried

```
string=[]
for line in f:
   String.append(line.split(None, 1)[0]) # add only first word
```

from another solution, but it keeps returning a "Index out of bounds" error.

I can get the first word from the first line using     `string=text.partition(' ')[0]`
but I do not know how to repeat this for the other lines.

I am still new to python and to the site, I hope my formatting is bearable! (when opened, I encode the text to accept symbols, like so 

`wikitxt=open('racinesPrefixesSuffixes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`
could this be the issue?)

Comment: Please don't post images. Post them as text. and don't name a variable as `string` as it is not a good practice

Comment: Will keep that in mind for next time, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's raising an `IndexError` is because the specific line is empty.
You can do this:

```
words = []
for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        words.append(line.split(maxsplit=1)[0])
```

Here `line.strip()` is checking if the line consists of only whitespace. If it does only consist of whitespace, it will simply skip the line.

Or, if you like [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html):

```
words = [line.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for line in f if line.strip()]
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it brings back  []. Here is my code from start to finish: (my god the formatting let me try to fix this)
`wikitxt=open('racinesPrefixesSuffixes.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')  

wiki=wikitxt.read()  

#taking specific part of the text file  

start = '#Racines'  

end = '#'  

racinesgros=((wiki.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])  

words = [line.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for line in wikitxt if line.strip()]  

print(words)`

If i use racinesgros instead of wikitxt in the function it will bring back every letter in the file in a list.

Comment: When you do `wiki=wikitxt.read()`, you're actually reading the entire file into a single string. Generally you don't want to do that, but if you must, you can replace `[line.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for line in wikitxt if line.strip()]` with `[line.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for line in wiki.splitlines() if line.strip()]`. The `str.splitlines()` function will split a string into a list of strings of the lines.

Comment: I see! that fixed it thank you so much! 

What generally would be the best way to import such a file into python to work with? I am not obligated to use it as a single string and I can see how it can cause issues.

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you. Since it appears you're trying to start and end at specific markers, you could use the `for` loop syntax above, except instead of immediately checking for the line, don't start actually splitting and appending until you run into a line that contains `start` using `start in line`. Once you've started and you run into a line that contains `end`, you can `break` out of the loop. Also check out the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) for idiomatic Python.