# How to get just the first word of every line of file using python?

Tags: python, automation, scripting

as you can see i'm a newbie and i don't know how to ask this question so i'm going to explain.
i was writing Somali dictionary in text format and i have a lot of words and their meaning, so i want to have those words only not their meaning in another text format file in order to have a list of only vocabulary. Is their a way i can do that. Example "**abaabid** m.dh eeg abaab². ld ababid. ld abaab¹, abaabis." I have hundred of these words and their meaning and i want to pick only the word "**abaabid**" and etc. so how can i automate it in python instead of copy pasting manually all day?. Stop saying post the code as text, i don't even know how to write the code and that's why i'm asking this question. [This screenshot is the text file showing words with their meaning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeaRq.png)

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.

Comment: So you want to have the 1st word from each line?

Comment: @white yes i want the first line of each

Comment: [How can you read just the first word of every line of file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645299/list-the-first-words-per-line-from-a-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a script to read the dictionary entries and then write the words into a separate file, try something like this:

```py
def get_words(filename='Somali Dictionary.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = [line.split()[0] for line in f.readlines() if line != '\n']
        f.close()
    return lines

def write_words(lines, filename='Somali Words.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)
            f.write('\n')
        f.close()
```

Example usage:

```py
words = get_words()
write_words(words)
```

Or, alternatively:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = get_words()
    write_words(words)
```

Comment: Here i found the solution[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162309/how-can-you-read-just-the-first-word-of-every-line-of-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first word of every line follow these steps

f = open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
print(line.split(' ')[0])
or

with open('convert.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
print(line.split(' ')[0])

If it shows you error in console about (UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode) you can fix by adding encoding='utf-8'(i'm using .txt file) and my file format is utf-8 and down below is how you are adding in your code

with open('convert.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
for line in f:
print(line.split(' ')[0])